# PrimeNG - Table merge 2 columns something

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using PrimeNG, I would with a conditional data, merge 2 columns (here, two cells horizontally) if the condition is true. But I don't see anything about that in the [documentation](https://primefaces.org/primeng/#/table). Is that even possible ? A little precision, I have to use ng-template. And the second thing is that I think `colspan` should not work here (because, I can not insert angular in it)

```
<p-dataTable *ngIf="preferencesTypes && preferencesTypes.length > 0" [value]="preferencesTypes">
<p-column field="message" header="Message">
  <ng-template let-col let-car="rowData" let-index="rowIndex" pTemplate="body">
    <div class="tooltip">
      <span>
        {{car.label}}
      </span>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</p-column>
<span>
  <p-column field="state" header="Yes">
    <ng-template let-col let-car="rowData" let-index="rowIndex" pTemplate="body">
      <p-radioButton *ngIf="car['type'] !== TYPE_VOID" [name]="'groupname_'+ index" [value]="getOptionName(car, 1)" [(ngModel)]="car[col.field]" (onClick)="myFunction(car, getOptionName(car, 1))"></p-radioButton>
      <span *ngIf="car['type'] === TYPE_CHOICE">{{car['options'][1].labels}}</span>
    </ng-template>
  </p-column>
  <p-column field="state" header="No">
    <ng-template let-col let-car="rowData" let-index="rowIndex" pTemplate="body" *ngIf="car['type'] !== TYPE_CHOICE">
      <p-radioButton *ngIf="car['type'] !== TYPE_VOID" [name]="'groupname_'+ index" [value]="getOptionName(car, 0)" [(ngModel)]="car[col.field]" (onClick)="myFunction(car, getOptionName(car, 0))"></p-radioButton>
      <span *ngIf="car['type'] === TYPE_CHOICE">{{car['options'][0].labels}}</span>
    </ng-template>
  </p-column>
</span>
```

The goal : If (type === TYPE_CHOICE) => merge yes and no columns, to put a dropdown instead of.

Comment: Please check this soltion - I guess you need smth similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40249952/primeng-datatable-colspan-tbody-solution

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it with simple *ngIf else statement.

Based on condition you can do it. if condition is true then add colspan in your th or td else normal th or td.

Please see below link for your reference.

[Prime ng table column group](https://primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/colgroup)